# if statement in grouped data

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to add new column named `'class'`  to my data  based on the conditions of the columns. I built user defined function called `class_fun` to create this new column.

I try to set entire sub-group to same value if the condition is matched. But I have not succeeded yet!

```
test=data.frame(set=as.numeric(gl(3,6)),gr = rep(letters[1:2],each=3),vals=c(c(10,10, 9, 8, 1,1),c(10,10,10, 9,6,2),c(10,7,6,1,1,2)))

> test
   set gr vals
1    1  a   10
2    1  a   10
3    1  a    9
4    1  b    8
5    1  b    1
6    1  b    1
7    2  a   10
8    2  a   10
9    2  a   10
10   2  b    9
11   2  b    6
12   2  b    2
13   3  a   10
14   3  a    7
15   3  a    6
16   3  b    1
17   3  b    1
18   3  b    2
```

## here is the function for creating a new column named `class`.

```
class_fun <- function(gr,set,vals){
  if(any(grepl("a|b",gr)&set==vals)){

    "catched"

  }
  else{

    NA
  }
}

library(dplyr)
test%>%
  group_by(set,gr)%>%
  mutate(class=class_fun(gr,set,vals))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   set, gr [6]
     set gr     vals class
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1 a        10 NA   
 2     1 a        10 NA   
 3     1 a         9 NA   
 4     1 b         8 NA   
 5     1 b         1 NA   
 6     1 b         1 NA   
 7     2 a        10 NA   
 8     2 a        10 NA   
 9     2 a        10 NA   
10     2 b         9 NA   
11     2 b         6 NA   
12     2 b         2 NA   
13     3 a        10 NA   
14     3 a         7 NA   
15     3 a         6 NA   
16     3 b         1 NA   
17     3 b         1 NA   
18     3 b         2 NA
```

What I was expecting is

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   set, gr [6]
     set gr     vals class
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1 a        10 NA   
 2     1 a        10 NA   
 3     1 a         9 NA   
 4     1 b         8 catched   
 5     1 b         1 catched
 6     1 b         1 catched
 7     2 a        10 NA   
 8     2 a        10 NA   
 9     2 a        10 NA   
10     2 b         9 catched   
11     2 b         6 catched   
12     2 b         2 catched  
13     3 a        10 NA   
14     3 a         7 NA   
15     3 a         6 NA   
16     3 b         1 NA   
17     3 b         1 NA   
18     3 b         2 NA
```

any idea or solution why this is happening ?
thx!

Comment: Why do you think those rows would match your condition? In no row does `a` or `b` appear in `set`, and in only three of the 6 you marked `catched` does `set` equal `vals`.

Comment: Can you say in words what you think the "class_fun" should do?

Comment: @CalumYou That is the trick. Setting the entire `class` column to `catched` in sub group `a`or`b`  even if only one rows is matched.

Comment: @MrFlick As I mentioned above the `class_fun` should set the entire class column to `catched` in sub group a or b even if only one rows is matched.

Comment: ok, but what is "matched". As you've written it no row has `set` contain `a` or `b`, so no row would be matched. Do you mean `gr`?

Comment: Maybe you mean `grepl("a|b", gr)` instead of `grepl("a|b",set)`? As Calum says, *in no row does `a` or `b` appear in `set`*

Comment: @Gregor oh Yes. So sorry! now  fixing it!

Comment: Sorry guys. Now fixed that issue.

Comment: how can the set be equal to the vals?? ie `set==vals`????

Comment: @Chris Yes I fixed in the OP. Please re-check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need to write a function .

```
test%>%group_by(set,gr)%>%mutate(calss=ifelse(any(stringr::str_detect(gr,'a|b')&(set==vals)),'catched',NA)
+ )
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   set, gr [6]
     set     gr  vals   calss
   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>   <chr>
 1     1      a    10    <NA>
 2     1      a    10    <NA>
 3     1      a     9    <NA>
 4     1      b     8 catched
 5     1      b     1 catched
 6     1      b     1 catched
 7     2      a    10    <NA>
 8     2      a    10    <NA>
 9     2      a    10    <NA>
10     2      b     9 catched
11     2      b     6 catched
12     2      b     2 catched
13     3      a    10    <NA>
14     3      a     7    <NA>
15     3      a     6    <NA>
16     3      b     1    <NA>
17     3      b     1    <NA>
18     3      b     2    <NA>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. This might work but I need to apply a function to my data because I have a bunch of conditions I would like to put them in a function.

Comment: @Alexander your function work for me , I think you have attached `plyr` and `dplyr`, try `test%>%
  group_by(set,gr)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(class=class_fun(gr,set,vals))`

Comment: @wow I re-loaded all of the packages and it worked. I never installed `plyr` but it might be some other packages like  ` ggplot2`  ` reshape2`  ` broom` might caused it. Thx a lot